# Como conectar duas Aplicações em uma mesma instancia do LocalDb

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-localdb, console-application

Estou com um problema na hora de conectar com uma mesma instancia do localDb em outra aplicação na mesma solução.

Detalhando o projeto, tenho uma aplicação ASP .NET MVC5 na solução e também uma outra aplicação de console na mesma solução.

Como construi o banco com code first na aplicação MVC, fix database first no console. Ele me gerou as classes das tabelas tudo certo, porém quando tento fazer alguma ação no banco da o seguinte erro:

> SqlException: Cannot attach file 'C:\Users\E555555\source\repos\PGP.WebSolution\Web\App_Data\aspnet-Web.mdf' as database 'Web' because this database name is already attached with file 'C:\Users\E555555\source\repos\PGP.WebSolution\Console\bin\Debug\aspnet-Web.mdf'

Pelo que entendi fala que não da para usar o mesmo no de banco de dados porque ja esta sendo usado por outro arquivo .mdf.

Porém não quero criar outro arquivo mdf, quero usar o existente ja.

E a connection string das duas aplicações são a mesma. Como posso usar o mesmo arquivo .mdf em mais de uma aplicação?

Quem puder ajudar agradeço.

```cs
//ConnectionString em ambas aplicações

<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Default" connectionString="data source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-BradescoPGPWeb.mdf;initial catalog=BradescoPGP.Web;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: tenta tirar a configuração initial catalog da sua string de conexão

Comment: Lucas Miranda, eu consegui resolver criando a base no SQLServer instalado na máquina mesmo, sem ser o .mdf, assim consegui acessar as bases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver essa questão usando uma instancia SQLServer instalada localmente na maquina. Assim consegui acessar sem problema a mesma base em dois projetos diferentes.